# Pairing BLE devices with mobile devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, android-bluetooth

Can we pair or bond the BLE-enabled device with a mobile device without an app? If not possible, why? And if possible, how?

So the use case is that whenever we tap in an NFC tag, the mobile devices pair with an esp32 by using BLE. I have already done this process using standard Bluetooth.

Comment: "I have already done this process using standard Bluetooth." - what have you done? Please edit your question and describe in detail what you already have. If you have already performed a Bluetooth pairing initiated by a NFC tag, what is your question?

Comment: Hey I have already done the process using standard Bluetooth now I want to try to connect it using Bluetooth low energy